# How to group object set by foreign key object set

Tags: python, django

Trying to figure out how to build a query grouping a List Model by a Group Model, and the List has a FK to Group (but not required). So I need "Lists Grouped", and then the remaining lists.

The structure to pass to the template would ideally be like this:

1. Group 1 (object)

   1. list 1 (object)
   2. list 2 (object)
2. Group 2 (object)

   1. list 3 (object)
   2. list 4 (object)
3. list 5 (object)
4. list 6 (object)

   ```
    class List(Publishable):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name="Title slug")
        excerpt = models.TextField(blank=True)
        description = models.TextField(blank=True)
        my_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
        group = models.ForeignKey(
            'ListGroup', verbose_name="List group", null=True, blank=True)

        class Meta(object):
            ordering = ('my_order',)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title


    class ListGroup(Publishable):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name="Title slug")
        excerpt = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
        description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
        my_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

        class Meta(object):
            ordering = ('my_order',)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title


    class ListsListView(ListView):

        model = List

        def groups_and_lists(self):

            ### Would like to returns something in this structure:

            # Group 1 (object)
                # - list 1 (object)
                # - list 2 (object)
            # Group 2 (object)
                # - list 3 (object)
                # - list 4 (object)

            ### Then remaining lists not in a group:

            # list 5 (object)
            # list 6 (object)

        def get_queryset(self):
            return List.objects.filter(
                Publishable.Q_PUBLISHED).order_by('my_order')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
return ListGroup.objects \
            .annotate(list_count=Count('lists')) \
            .filter(list_count__gte=1) \
            .order_by('my_order') \
            .prefetch_related('lists')
```